# Android Tablet Internal Storage

Tags: android, tablet

1)I am converting an ipad project to android.In doing so,in ipad 
version ,I can save the internal files in bundle (called Bundle 
directory) and all the files are stored under Documents which is 
internal to app.

In android we have /data/data/{package name}/files

My Question is I should be able to store large data inside the 
internal storage.Does tablet have large internal space(atleast latest version) ?I dont want to save the files in sdcard either because it can be replaced or something.

Is the device RAM used for internal storage of files?I am facing a memory problem where as in ios we can have sufficient data stored in application sandbox...I need to copy files from assets to in internal storage during run time(by files I mean large files). 
Can somebody throw light on this.Thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Internal storage is separate from RAM in android.
- The amount of internal storage varies from device to device
- Its not entirely uncommon to copy large assets (like pre-made databases) onto the tablets internal storage for applications to function properly so it shouldn't be a problem for you.

Comment: Thanks Justin for response.I might have huge media files too.I cant have these in sd card since I want it sandboxed.So in that case too,it shouldnt be a problem right?

Comment: If by sandboxed, you mean you want the media files removed when your appication is uninstalled, then you do still have options on the external sd card. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#ExternalCache. That being said, if you just want to rely on internal storage, nothing prevents you from doing this. The user is capable of deleting this data (through Clear User Data), so you should always make sure it exists before you attempt to use it.

Comment: Thanks Justin,By sandbox,I meant that the applications data shd not be world seen.If you store in sdcard or external storage I guess everyone can see it when sdcard is mounted on a usb drive or can be shared by other applications.Just wanted to save the files where none others can see.So I guess I will need to use the internal storage.

Comment: Sure thing. Please be sure to accept my answer via the checkbox next to it if I solved your problem. As a side note, you may want to put a file with name ".nomedia" in your folder to be extra sure Androids media scanner does not pick up your images / videos. Finally, people who root their phones are capable of browsing your internal storage, but there isn't much you can do about that.